# Prestigio Multipad USB debuging

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

I am having troubles with Prestigio Multipad PMP3370B. I enabled USB debuging in Settings, but when I plug in my device to a computer and start adb devices, it does not recognize it. Does anybody have any similar issues? I am using Windows 7. Where can I find Windows driver for that device?

Answer (score 3):

You can find USB drivers for the **Prestigio Multipad PMP3370B** (aka **Prestigio MultiPad 7.0 ULTRA**) in the [manufacturer website](http://www.prestigio.com/catalogue/Archive_products/Multipads/MultiPad_7.0_Ultra#/product-support/firmware)

Just click the download link for the .zip file corresponding to your model, as seen in the screenshot.

[image: website screenshot]

At the time of this answer, the file name is `PMP3370B_20121217_V1.0.8.zip`, this file is ~224 MB size and **it does contain USB drivers** for Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7 (32-bit) and Windows Vista/7 (64-bit), besides firmware update image file, upgrade manuals (in English/Russian, 32/64-bit) and other tools. I can tell it because I downloaded it myself and looked inside.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you can find drivers for your specific device; but for most devices (of different manufacturers), Koush's [universal adb driver](http://adbdriver.com/) does a good job on Windows 7 and 8 as well. You can download them from the linked site, and find instructions there as well.